# Nutch: Authentication via putting a cookie in the header

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, solr, nutch

I am surprised that there is so little support or information out there for getting Nutch to be able to crawl parts of a website that require authentication.

I am aware that maybe Apache Nutch is not currently able to ([but apparently hopes to](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/HttpPostAuthentication)) support Http POST authentication.

However, all we really want to do is be able to add a cookie to our Nutch bot header that will allow it to access those parts of the site that way (rather than post a username and password to a form and then receive the cookie).

So I have spent a good amount of time searching and am surprised that most discussions about this are all the way back in 2005 or 2008: [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/bhVEvThyYNqvmgycVlKM#0N7zAPMhbM3xOnX), [there](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/httpclient-and-cookies-td616513.html), [everywhere](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-authenticate-with-cookies-td614810.html).

After all these years, is there anyway to work around this limitation or is there just still no way to authenticate by giving Nutch a 'prebaked' cookie so it can access member only parts of our site?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added custom code to nutch protocol-httpclient plugin to solve the issue.

Shared the changes in the link below

http://www.gingercart.com/Home/search-and-crawl/nutch-custom-authentication-cookies-session-management-to-crawl-secure-enterprise-websites

Comment: Hi Mouli,
The code that you have mentioned in above link is good However There are no import statement because I which I am getting Compile time errors.
Also Could you please share the link where you have uploaded the complete Code for Formed based Authentication

Comment: Hi Jayesh, I have added the imports. unfortunately i cant share the java file as it has some sensitive content. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi Mouli,
Thanks for adding the import statement. However Could you please tell me from where would you call following function?
    protected Response getResponse(URL url, WebPage page, boolean redirect)
            throws ProtocolException, IOException {
        }

Comment: Hi Jayesh, We are overriding existing call back method (getResponse). it will be called at the time of crawl by nutch. No need to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe nutch has added cookies.txt in the latest release 1.19. I'm trying to evaluate if that would solve this purpose.

https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@nutch.apache.org/msg03012.html