# Nutch1.X add COOKIE to request

Tags: java, cookies, social-networking, nutch

I am new to Nutch.I have an idea of collecting user's data of qzone( a social network in China).

I know how to use Apache HttpClient to send request with cookie ,but I want to enlarge my program to catch data with more than one PC.I am using Java and find Nutch is a good choice.I need add cookie to my request and don't know how to do.
After searching the Internet ,I found no such demos or references.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on asking questions.  Stack overflow is a great place to get help for specific problems.  Please try and show us what you have already tried.

Comment: @Brody I have search "Nutch" and "cookie" on stackoverflow,and I found only one which is suit me[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581298/nutch-authentication-via-putting-a-cookie-in-the-header),but I cannot understand because it is too simple.Thanks!